# How to get the productId from an iOS consumable in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

On my server, I am calling Apple's `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` endpoint which returns a [json object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody) with [receipt data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/receipt).

However, this object doesn't seem to have the `productId` of the purchased in-app purchase.

I need to know the productId so I actually know which IAP was bought...surely there is some sort of identifier for the actual product purchased?

Comment: The in app purchase details are in the receipt your app passes to your server. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html  You don't need to get it from the verification response; the verification response tells you that you can trust (or not) the receipt you received from your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in-app purchase transactions are stored in the array `in_app` of `responseBody`. Each object in `in_app` contains field `product_id`:

[image]

The full list of `in_app` fields is here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/receipt/in_app